# HTTP to URL in Flask

Tags: python, http, flask

I am trying to construct a page that autofills the url with the selection from a list in the previous page.
Currently my code looks like:

```
import flask
import json
from flask import request, render_template 
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    result_list = ['hola','mundo']
    return render_template(
        'index.html',
        data=result_list)

@app.route('/area' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def area():
    select = request.form.get('comp_select')
    return render_template('area.html',data=select)
```

What I want is 'comp_select' to be an http request like so:

```
@app.route('/area?select= <request.form.get('comp_select')>' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def area():
    if 'select' in request.args:
        select = request.args['select']
    else:
        return "Error: No select field provided. Please specify selection."
    return render_template('area.html',data=select)
```

This way the users selection from the first page can be bookmarked. I know it can be done, but I'm struggling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm, not sure why you want to read from the form.

I think, the below code serves the same purpose.

```
@app.route("/area", methods=['GET', 'POST']) \
def area():
    select = request.args.get("select", default=None, type=str)
    if select is not None and request.form.get('comp_select') == select:
        return render_template('area.html', data=select)
    
    return "Error: No select field provided. Please specify selection."
```

Comment: Totally, I hear you. The reason is I want whatever the selection is to go into the URI so that it can be bookmarked. I need the selection from the form to build the next page, so it throws an error (of course) if anyone tries to visit /area without a selection.

Comment: I think I might need to construct the selection in the previous page is the answer

Comment: @DataMCBBA I've just updated, with a check on form data. I hope it ensures the form selection too.

Comment: I'm trying to get whatever the user selects on the first page to populate the URI  on the second page. For instance if the user selects 'Hola' I want that to feed into 'def area()' so that its URI reads '/area?select=Hola' automatically